# Help me get rid of the space " "

Tags: ruby

```
def name
  @name || "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

If first name and last name are both empty name is a space " ". How do I rewrite the right-hand side so it's an empty string "" instead of a space " "?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just add `.strip` at the end:

```
>> ln = 'last' #=> "last"
>> fn = 'first' #=> "first"
>> "#{fn} #{ln}".strip #=> "first last"
>> fn = nil #=> nil
>> ln = nil #=> nil
>> "#{fn} #{ln}".strip #=> ""
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def name
  @name ||= [first_name, last_name].compact * " "
end
```

This solution has the advantage of not including a trailing or leading space when either name is `nil`, **and** it works in the general case (i.e. for any number of strings).

Comment: Does `*` here have the same effect as `join`? I didn't know that usage.

Comment: @sawa: If the parameter is a string it will do the same as `join`, otherwise it will repeat the string x times (`>> %w(a b c) * ", " #=> "a, b, c"`).